# JFreeChart XYSplineRenderer Demo

Tags: java, jfreechart

Would someone please point me to a working example JFreeChart's XYSplineRenderer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I've never seen the example, `XYSplineRendererDemo1.java` is one that may be found among the [demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html). All the demos are included with the [developer guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)<sup>†</sup>, which I recommend highly.

If you want to assay an example of your own, note that `XYSplineRenderer` is an `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, so start with a matching [`ChartFactory`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html). It looks like they all take an `XYDataset`.

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer: Not affiliated with Object Refinery Limited; just a satisfied customer and very minor contributor.*</sub>