# Setting multiple colours in 3D BarChart - JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm new to the JFreeChart library. I'm currently playing around with the 3D Bar Chart, and I wonder if it is possible to have each generated 3D bar in different colours? All of them are currently yellow as shown below.

Is there something I can override to change the colours?

Thanks.

***Code:***

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class jfree extends ApplicationFrame
{
    {
        // set a theme using the new shadow generator feature available in
        // 1.0.14 - for backwards compatibility it is not enabled by default
        ChartFactory.setChartTheme(StandardChartTheme.createDarknessTheme());
    }

    public jfree(String s)
    {
        super(s);
        JPanel jpanel = createDemoPanel();
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(jpanel);
    }

    private static CategoryDataset createDataset()
    {
        DefaultCategoryDataset defaultcategorydataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
                    defaultcategorydataset.addValue(25D, "Series 1", "Pipe Stricking");
                    defaultcategorydataset.addValue(17D, "Series 1", "Lost Circulation");
                    defaultcategorydataset.addValue(34D, "Series 1", "Hole Deviation");
                    defaultcategorydataset.addValue(12D, "Series 1", "Kick Blowout");
                    defaultcategorydataset.addValue(54D, "Series 1", "Formation Change");
                    defaultcategorydataset.addValue(10D, "Series 1", "Borehole Instability");
                    defaultcategorydataset.addValue(19D, "Series 1", "Cavings/Pack-offs");
        return defaultcategorydataset;
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset categorydataset)
    {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("IPS", "", "Value", categorydataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
                    CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();
                    CategoryAxis categoryaxis = categoryplot.getDomainAxis();
                    categoryaxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(0.2D));
                    CategoryItemRenderer categoryitemrenderer = categoryplot.getRenderer();
                    categoryitemrenderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
                    BarRenderer barrenderer = (BarRenderer)categoryitemrenderer;
                    barrenderer.setItemMargin(200D);
        return jfreechart;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel()
    {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        jfree jfree = new jfree("3D Bar Chart Demo 3");
        jfree.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(jfree);
        jfree.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: JFree3DBarChart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the bars are the same color because they all belong to the same series, identified by the `rowKey` parameter in `addValue()`. Two common approaches to changing the color include these:

- Invoke `setSeriesPaint()`, as shown in the [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html) [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.65).
- Override `getItemPaint()` to define a custom color scheme, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006785/230513).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Despite the fact that they belong to the same series and all have the same colours, can I have the bars in different colours even if they are in a single series? 
`setSeriesPaint()` just changes the colour for the series and not the bars.

Comment: Yes, override `getItemPaint()`; here's a more elaborate [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8949913/230513).

Comment: Thank you, are you on the dev team of the library?

Comment: No, just a fan of the project; usual disclaimer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12272267/230513). :-)