# Animate plot on JFreeChart line graph

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm currently working on a project that plots real time data as a line graph using the JFreeChart library. It's working great, but I want to give it a little more elegance by plotting the data in a smooth animated manner, rather than plotting in discrete steps. A good example of the effect I'm looking for can be found here:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

Notice how the lines are animated between plot points.

I'm currently using the inbuilt XYLineChart for my graphs.

Is there a simple (or existing) way to achieve this effect, or will I have to dig deep into the library to implement these changes manually?

Answer (score 1):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513), the `process()` implementation of a `SwingWorker` updates an `XYSeries` using values sent via the background thread's `publish()` method. The enclosing `ChartPanel` listens to the chart and updates itself in response.

If the calculation has no significant latency, use `javax.swing.Timer`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513).

[image]

Addendum: *What I'm looking for is a smooth animation of the line between each plot point.*

There is no general substitute for the absence of data, but you can add points from a known function or [interpolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) based on existing data. Also consider `XYSplineRenderer`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12272267/230513) and seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790187/230513).

[image]

Comment: This would still plot each point in discrete steps though, right? What I'm looking for is a smooth animation of the line between each plot point.

Comment: Exactly; I've elaborated above.