# Animate the drawing of XYSplineRenderer

Tags: java, animation, jfreechart

I want to animate the drawing of `XYSplineRenderer`. The animation should be smooth and in the future I want to be able to modify the velocity. But at the moment just a smooth animation would be fine.

I was reading about `SwingWorker` and also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065053/animate-plot-on-jfreechart-line-graph), however I really cannot figure out how to work with `XYSeries`. How should I add points to `series` inside `doInBackground` (it says that XYSeries is not iterable)?

Any example would be really appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            GUI t = new GUI();
            t.runCalc();
        }
    });
}


public void runCalc() {
    TwoWorker task = new TwoWorker();
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    });
    task.execute();
}

// UNDER CONSTRUCTION !!!
private class TwoWorker extends SwingWorker<Double, Double> 
{
    @Override
    protected XYSeries doInBackground() throws Exception
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.size(); i++) 
        {
            series.add(solution.point(i).lat(),solution.point(i).lon());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return XYSeries;
    }
}
```

P.S. `solution` is just the collection of points defined by latitude and longitude. Based on this points, `XYSplineRenderer` is constructed.

Answer (score 2):

*Always* update Swing components and models, like `ChartPanel` and `XYSeries`, on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Your example calls `series.add()` in the background, while @trashgod's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068849/261156) calls `publish()` in the background. The published results get handled in `process()`, which *does* run on the event dispatch thread.

Start with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/261156) and change it like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/261156) to see how it works.